# Access a Dictionary index saved in Swift session

Tags: ios, swift, session-variables, swift-dictionary

So I basically have a login screen on my app and after a successful login, before performing a segue to the main screen I save the following info in a Dictionary in session. It's something like this (putting static info for the example):

```swift
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let session_info : [String: String] = [
        "user_id": "123",
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@doe.com"
    ]
    preferences.set(session_info, forKey: "session")
    preferences.synchronize()
```

So the session data gets saved, if I assign it to a variable and print it, I get an optional dictionary of info in my console.

```swift
    let session_data = preferences.value(forKey: "session")!
```

If I do a `print(session_data)` I get this output:

```swift
   {
       "user_id" = "123";
       "name" = "John";
       "email" = "john@doe.com";
   }
```

My issue is that I am not sure how to access the keys, because if I treat the assigned variable as a Dictionary it says `Type 'Any' has no subscript members.` What I use is this:

```swift
   print(session_data["user_id"])
```

Is there a way to access this info or do I have to save each variable to a separate session key?

Comment: Just a small comment on your code, you shouldn't call `synchronize()` on `UserDefaults`. As stated in the documentation, "this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used".

Comment: But from what I read the phone does it from time to time and I need to ensure that info gets saved. Or did I read wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically never use `value(forKey` with `UserDefaults`.

There is a dedicated API [`dictionary(forKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1408563-dictionary) which returns `[String:Any]?` by default. In your case conditionally downcast the dictionary to `[String:String]`.

```
if let sessionData = preferences.dictionary(forKey: "session") as? [String:String] {
   print(sessionData["user_id"]!)
} else {
   print("sessionData is not available")
}
```

And this is not JavaScript. Please name variables *lowerCamelCased*.

---

A more sophisticated way is to use a struct and save it with `Codable`

```
struct Session : Codable {
    let userID, name, email : String
}

let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
let sessionInfo = Session(userID:"123", name: "John", email: "john@doe.com")
let sessionData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(sessionInfo)
preferences.set(sessionData, forKey: "session")
```

---

```
do {
    if let sessionData = preferences.data(forKey: "session") {
        let sessionInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode(Session.self, from: sessionData)
        print(sessionInfo.userID)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfect for me. So basically I have to recast the Dictionary as the original structure I used for it in order to be able to use it?

Comment: It depends on your needs. The struct method is just an alternative. The benefit it that you get rid of dealing with keys and casting type.

Answer (score -1):

You have to parse it as a `Dictionary`.

```
guard let session_data = preferences.value(forKey: "session")! as? NSDictionary else {return }
print(session_data["user_id"])
```

It should works.

Comment: (1) You should use `Dictionary`, not `NSDictionary`.(2)  Force-unwrapping the result of `value(forKey:)` is a bad idea since it will crash if Defaults does not contain an entry for that key. (3) vadian's suggestion of using the `Defaults` method `dictionary(forKey:)` is cleaner than using conditional casting.